# Pointing to certain id not working PHP

Tags: php, mysql, get

I'm trying to delete a row from a MySQL table using PHP. I have visited many pages already but I can't find a reason why I can't make it work.

Contacts.php

```
require_once "functions.php";
$db = new DatabaseConnection();
$user = new AddressBook($db->pdo);

<table>
            <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th>Direccion</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $i=0;
                $contactos=$user->verContactos();
                foreach($contactos as $conts){
                    $i++;
                ?>

            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $conts['nombre']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $conts['telefono']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $conts['direccion']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $conts['email']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="borrar.php?id<?php $conts['id']; ?>">Borrar</a></td></tr>

            </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
 {
     $id = $_GET['id'];
     $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id=$id")
     or die(mysql_error()); 



    header("Location: contacts.php");
    }
      else
    {
      header("Location: contacts.php");
    }


?>
```

I know you're gonna say mysql is not useful anymore. In my web system I have this part using a function and PDO extension.
It doesn't matter if I use this example or my version using PDO, I cannot get the id. I just get something like this:

http://localhost/agenda/borrar.php?id     <- Missing ID

The id field in database is called 'id'. I think the problem may be the use of $_GET but I can't find it.

Comment: (1) you are missing `=` after `id`. (2) you are missing an `echo`. -> `<a href="borrar.php?id<?php $conts['id']; ?>">` should be `<a href="borrar.php?id=<?php echo $conts['id']; ?>">`

Comment: Also, your link is `borrar.php`, but your code is in `delete.php`?

Comment: borrar and delete confusion was not the problem. I have the correct names, I just wanted to change it to English, thus you could understand what I was trying to do but I forgot to change one php file name.
Such a silly mistake, I did those corrections and it works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<td><a href="borrar.php?id<?php $conts['id']; ?>">Borrar</a></td></tr>
```

Needs to be this:

```
<td><a href="borrar.php?id=<?php echo $conts['id']; ?>">Borrar</a></td></tr>
```

And this:

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id=$id")
```

Needs to be this:

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id=" . intval($id))
```

Comment: it might be good to also include the `echo` issue in `<a href="borrar.php?id<?php $conts['id']; ?>">Borrar</a>` that I pointed out [16 mins ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050765/pointing-to-certain-id-not-working-php#comment59749881_36050765)

Comment: Good catch; I've fixed that.